# How to multiply a constant for each month by the original time series using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I am using python to look at monthly climate data.  Basically, I have calculated averages for both the observed values and simulated values of each month.  I am "normalizing" or multiplying the entire simulated timeseries by the ratio observed/simulated from 1964-2013 (1 value for each month).  How do I multiply the constant for each month by that respective month throughout the entire timeseries?

**Observed Dataset**

```
Date           Obs   
1964-01-01  2.362798
1964-02-01  2.581734
1964-03-01  1.978354
1964-04-01  1.297320
1964-05-01  2.419230
1964-06-01  1.792333
1964-07-01  1.241412
1964-08-01  1.738074
1964-09-01  0.232911
1964-10-01 -1.790989
1964-11-01  1.902479
1964-12-01  2.304906
1965-01-01  2.913466
1965-02-01  2.895884
1965-03-01  2.457741
1965-04-01  3.435275
1965-05-01  4.428590
1965-06-01  4.530668
1965-07-01  4.096984
1965-08-01  3.543258
1965-09-01  2.856509
1965-10-01  2.817188
1965-11-01  3.838903
1965-12-01  3.985564
...
```

**Simulated Dataset**

```
Date            Sim
1964-01-01    4.114642
1964-02-01    4.115002
1964-03-01    4.524121
1964-04-01    4.490407
1964-05-01    4.771731
1964-06-01    5.308645
1964-07-01    4.921411
1964-08-01    4.690133
1964-09-01    4.377383
1964-10-01    4.810576
1964-11-01    4.775757
1964-12-01    4.323243
1965-01-01    4.264359
1965-02-01    4.347614
1965-03-01    4.409341
1965-04-01    4.570921
1965-05-01    5.131675
1965-06-01    4.950372
1965-07-01    4.711410
1965-08-01    4.460363
1965-09-01    4.223364
1965-10-01    4.092056
1965-11-01    4.102400
1965-12-01    3.963300
...
```

I know how to find the average of each month for both datasets using:

```
    obs_mean=OBS.groupby(OBS.index.strftime("%m")).mean()
    sim_mean=SIM.groupby(OBS.index.strftime("%m")).mean()
```

Then I can get a ratio of observed/simulated by:

```
    obsarray = np.squeeze(obs_mean.values)
    simarray= np.squeeze(sim_mean.values)
    N_mean=(obsarray)/(simarray)
```

N_mean yield the following:

```
[0.74664557 0.75842637 0.72030754 0.68142632 0.68588863 0.56606582
 0.54309691 0.54699926 0.50097214 0.48727185 0.71990437 0.75965146]
```

How do I apply this N_mean value, for each month, to each respective month in the original simulated timeseries.  So, for January N=0.74664557, I want to multiply this coefficient by each January value on the simulated timeseries.  Another thing to keep in mind is that this coefficient is based on the 50-year baseline (1964-2013) and I want to apply this coefficient to a larger simulated timeseries (1950-2100).  Is this easier to accomplish within the pandas framework?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute the ratio using `groupby` and `mean`, then use `reindex` to broadcast the result across all rows of `sim` and multiply.

```
u = pd.concat([obs, sim], axis=1)
v = u.groupby(u.index.month).mean().eval('Obs / Sim')

sim.mul(v.reindex(obs.index.month).values, axis=0)
```

Comment: I think the groupby index.month wouldn't work in this case because the data spans multiple years

Comment: @SvenHarris "I am using python to look at monthly climate data" so, years are irrelevant

Comment: Yeah you're right, that makes sense, misread the data/question

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!  If I have about 20 more columns of simulated data, how could I go through doing this procedure on each column most efficiently?

Comment: @JeffColdplume Do you mean to say that each DataFrame could have 20 columns (such as obs1, obs2, .... and sim1, sim2, ...)?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify.  Only 1 column of observed data, but 20 columns of simulated data.  The simulation from above is just one of those columns.  So I will have a different N_mean value for each simulation using the procedure outlined above.  This means the coefficient for each month will be dictated by the denominator (Sim) and should be different for each simulation.

Comment: @JeffColdplume I understand. Would it be possible to open a follow-up question for this? Please link to this question saying this is a follow-up and you are requesting a solution when `sim` has multiple columns. You don't need to have 20 columns, just 3-5 is enough. And about 15-20 rows is enough as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you first merge the two frames together, (looks like you're using a shared time index)

```
joined_df = obs_df.join(sim_df, how="outer")
```

You can then apply-transform your groupby values to create new columns in your original DataFrame

```
joined_df[["sim_mean", "obs_mean"]] = joined_df.groupby(joined_df.index.month)[["Sim", "Obs"]].transform("mean")
```

You can then find a ratio of the columns

```
joined_df["n_mean"] = joined_df["obs_mean"]/joined_df["sim_mean"]
```